# Angular spy RxJS observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, jasmine

I want to test a service and mock the provider it gets. The problem is that I call an observable of that provider which I cant spy on:

```
export class MyDataService {
  destroy$ = new Subject();

  constructor(
    private wsService: WebsocketService
  ) {
    this.wsService
      .connected$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe(connected => this.onConnected(connected));
   }

   myCoolFunction() {
      // ...
   }

   ngOnDestory() {
      this.destroy.next();
      this.destroy.complete();
   }
}
```

My test:

```
describe('MyDataService', () => {
  let service: MyDataService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const websocketServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('WebsocketService', [], ['connected$']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide:  WebsocketService,
          useValue: websocketServiceSpy,
        }
      ],
    });
    service             = TestBed.inject(MyDataService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

But it throws:

> Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined

How can I spy this.wsService.connected$ correctly?

Comment: Why *spy* something that's not a method? It's just a prop whose value is an observable e.g. `websocketServiceSpy.connected$ = someSubject.asObservable()`.

Comment: Note also that you've neatly demoed why the Angular style guide [recommends using the interfaces for lifecycle methods](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#implement-lifecycle-hook-interfaces): ngOnDestory...

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added it manually in the example. Obviously I always add the interface, otherwise talint would comply